# JPA persistence property interfering with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, unmarshalling

I have a library of JAXB/Entity objects I am using to unmarshall a xml stream.  I can do so with no problems just running as a Java SE application. I have moved everything over to a Java EE app using Netbeans 6.9 and Glassfish 3.01.  I am now running into a number of exceptions like the following.

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 19 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Property _persistence_productBase_vh is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at protected org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.WeavedAttributeValueHolderInterface entitiesjaxb.cmic.ajrs.com.ProductSorts._persistence_productBase_vh
                at entitiesjaxb.cmic.ajrs.com.ProductSorts
                at public entitiesjaxb.cmic.ajrs.com.ProductSorts entitiesjaxb.cmic.ajrs.com.ObjectFactory.createProductSorts()
                at entitiesjaxb.cmic.ajrs.com.ObjectFactory
```

My problem is that there is no xml element or variable _persistence_productBase_vh anywhere in my enties/jaxb files. I assume this is being added by Glassfish and EclipseLink.  Does anyone know any way to make these properties ignored?  Here is the entity and a sample from the xml.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ProductSorts", propOrder = {
    "pkId",
    "productBase",
    "field",
    "value",
    "ts"
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_sorts")
@NamedQueries({
    //@NamedQuery(name = "ProductSorts.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductSorts p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductSorts.findByPkId", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductSorts p WHERE p.pkId = :pkId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductSorts.findByField", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductSorts p WHERE p.field = :field"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductSorts.findByValue", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductSorts p WHERE p.value = :value"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductSorts.findByTs", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductSorts p WHERE p.ts = :ts")})
public class ProductSorts implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pk_id")
    private Integer pkId;
    @Column(name = "field")
    @XmlElement(name = "Field")
    private String field;
    @Column(name = "value")
    @XmlElement(name = "Value")
    private String value;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ts")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    private Date ts;
    @JoinColumn(name = "pk_product", referencedColumnName = "pk_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ProductBase productBase;

    public ProductSorts() {
    }

    public ProductSorts(Integer pkId) {
        this.pkId = pkId;
    }



<ProductSorts>
  <pkID>317926</pkID>
  <pkProduct>118647</pkProduct>
  <Field>3D TECHNOLOGY</Field>
  <Value>No</Value>
  <ts>1970-01-13T00:43:15.947</ts>
</ProductSorts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property (_persistence_productBase_vh) has been woven onto the JPA entity.  You can use property access in your JAXB mappings to get around this issue.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
```

When EclipseLink does bytecode weaving it checks for JAXB on the classpath.  If JAXB is present it will weave that property with the @XmlTransient annotation.  Are you using static or dynamic weaving? If you are using static weaving you will need to ensure that the JAXB API jar is on your class path.

Comment: Hmm, I am not 100% sure. I would like to say static weaving as I have the JAXB classes in a library that has no ability to regenerate them. They originally were generated with netbeans 6.9, then I combined my entities and the JAXB classes and moved them to a new library.

Comment: I am working on the XmlAccessType of PROPERTY right now. For some reason that increased my illegal annotations by five. If what I see in the JPA javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType docs is right I should only be seeing attempts to bind values with a getter/setter  pair which matches up to the five fields I had defined.....Ohh I see now, the new errors come from the @Column annotation and the @XmlElement annotations having the same values

Comment: @grantk - When you use XmlAccessType of PROPERTY you need to annotate the get methods instead of the fields.  This is what is causing the illegal annotation exceptions.

Comment: Blaise, thank you I did not realize that.  Would that still be the @XmlElement annotation on the get method?

Comment: @grantk - Yes, the exact same JAXB annotations you had on the field would move to the get methods.  The JPA annotations would stay where they currently are.